# On Subsequences and Divergence of Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

We know that if a sequence X has two convergent subsequences, whose limits are not equal, then X is divergent. For example: $(-1)^n$

However, **is it true that for a given divergent sequence, we can necessarily find at least two convergent subsequences whose limits are unequal**? Please help in proving or disproving this claim!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take the sequence $a_n=n$. It does not have any convergent subsequences.

**EDIT:**
Let $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Then $n_k \geq k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ since $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is a strictly monotonically increasing sequence. This implies $a_{n_k}\geq k$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. Therefore the subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge.

Comment: True! Well observed! A rigorous proof would be great, though

Comment: @arya_stark I have added a proof.